# ReactJS - docx file currupted when download using Blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I have this function use to download the file that backend response to me:

```
function downloadFile(res, fileName) {
    try {
      const blob = new Blob([res?.data], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      });

      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      a.click();
      setTimeout(() => {
        // Clean up the URL object after some time
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }, 100);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error downloading file:", error);
    }
  }
```

After download the file is corrupted:
[image]

This is the response in devtool:
[image]

I tried adding `responseType: "blob"` in the request's header but still same result, this is how the file supposed to look like:
[image]